# when i am trying to running build commad i am getting the below error message build iOS app

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Launching lib/main.dart on Gedo iPhone in debug mode...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: xxxxx
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           91.5s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): lib/helper/notification_helper.dart:22:29: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'IOSInitializationSettings'.

Error launching application on Gedo iPhone.

flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && rm -f Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 0):

You can enter to XCode and run application for the iPhone. You will get the same error. Then you need to tap error icon and it leads to signing page. Input correct variation and run from XCode again. When it runs then you can exit from XCode and run from Android Studio again.

Answer (score 0):

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
> ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
> import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
> .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.

- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
  ^
  ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
  .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
  ^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception